# Suppressing display in docker

Tags: docker, qt, user-interface, display

I have a docker image with a medical data analysis app installed in it. The app works from both gui and console. Normally, in my linux, I run the app from the terminal as

```
./dsi_studio --action=trk ...
```

and it works quite smoothly. If you click on this app, it'll try to open a GUI. While I'm trying to use this inside the docker image, it tries to connect to the display in any case (even if I run as shown in the terminal). And, of course, since I didn't do any setup for showing GUI from docker, I get the following error, stating that it couldn't find a display to connect.

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I don't know why the app is trying to open a display while running in terminal, because it doesn't open a GUI in my linux. I just want to suppress this warning somehow, as if there is a fake display. I don't want to connect my display to docker image, because this image is going to run in batch in an HPC.

So, How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably export the DISPLAY environment variable to point to your linux terminal.
Just to test, run

```
xhost +
```

in your linux terminal and add

```
-e DISPLAY=:0.0
```

to your docker command line